# How to find the terms for all possible three dimensional even rational functions up to a certain degree

Tags: algorithms, rational-functions, parity

I need to approximate the solutions of a differential equation using rational functions.

A) The solution is of the form f(x,y,z) = N / D where D needs to be a polynomial of higher order than N so it goes to zero as x and y increases.

B) I am assuming that f(x,y,z)=f(-x,y,z)=f(x,-y,z)  for the solution, so i need to test different rational functions and they all must be even functions (i guess).

C) The maximum order for the polynomials should be N1 = N2 = 4, for the numerator and denominator respectively, but polynomials with lower orders should be considered as well.

I know that if both numerator and denominator polynomials have the same parity, then the resulting function will be even.

But is there a way of sistematically generating all polynomial divisions that will suffice the above conditions?

Thanks a lot.

PS: After i have a set of rational functions that agree with the above conditions, i will use those functions to create an analytical solution aproximation of the original equation (diffusion equation) using optimization algorithms to find the optimal polynomial coefficients.

Comment: There are infinitely many such functions for any $N_1$ and $N_2$, as your coefficients are entirely unrestricted. So asking for *all* possible combinations seems like a bit much.

Comment: Are these functions of $x, y,$ and $z$? Or do you mean that $z$ will be a function of $x$ and $y$? In either case, graphing is going to require more than $2$ dimensions (either $4$, or $3$, respectively), so I am unclear if by "symmetry over the $y$ axis" you mean $f(x,y,z) = f(-x, y, -z)$ or $z(x,y) = z(-x,y)$. The nature of the polynomials needed differs in these two cases.

Comment: @servaes well, you could assume that all coefficients are equal to unity, if that makes any difference. I am really interested now in what are the polynomials up to the Nth power that when divided by another to the N2th power would result in a even rational function. How can one find them whithout brute force checking every single combination of terms?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - i updated the question to make it clearer. Thanks for your comment.